# Quickest way to assign cell values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of tuples:

```
d = [("a", "x"), ("b", "y"), ("a", "y")]
```

and the `DataFrame`:

```
     y    x
b  0.0  0.0
a  0.0  0.0
```

I would like to replace any `0s` with `1s` if the row and column labels correspond to a tuple in `d`, such that the new DataFrame is:

```
     y    x
b  1.0  0.0
a  1.0  1.0
```

I am currently using:

```
for i, j in d:
    df.loc[i, j] = 1.0
```

This seems to me as the most "pythonic" approach but for a `DataFrame` of shape 20000 * 20000 and a list of length 10000, this process literally takes forever. There must be a better way of accomplishing this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Pandas is not a best tool for such kind of manipulations. Based on your description I think you need to look to Sparse matrices (scipy.sparse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1: No bad entries in `d`**

Here's one NumPy based method -

```
def assign_val(df, d, newval=1):    
    # Get d-rows,cols as arrays for efficient usage latet on
    di,dc = np.array([j[0]  for j in d]), np.array([j[1]  for j in d])

    # Get col and index data
    i,c = df.index.values.astype(di.dtype),df.columns.values.astype(dc.dtype)

    # Locate row indexes from d back to df
    sidx_i = i.argsort()
    I = sidx_i[np.searchsorted(i,di,sorter=sidx_i)]

    # Locate column indexes from d back to df
    sidx_c = c.argsort()
    C = sidx_c[np.searchsorted(c,dc,sorter=sidx_c)]

    # Assign into array data with new values
    df.values[I,C] = newval
    # Use df.to_numpy(copy=False)[I,C] = newval on newer pandas versions
    return df
```

Sample run -

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2,2)), columns=['y','x'], index=['b','a'])

In [22]: d = [("a", "x"), ("b", "y"), ('a','y')]

In [23]: assign_val(df, d, newval=1)
Out[23]: 
     y    x
b  1.0  0.0
a  1.0  1.0
```

**Approach #2: Generic one**

If there are any *bad* entries in `d, we need to filter out those. So, a modified one for that generic case would be -

```
def ssidx(i,di):
    sidx_i = i.argsort()
    idx_i = np.searchsorted(i,di,sorter=sidx_i)
    invalid_mask = idx_i==len(sidx_i)
    idx_i[invalid_mask] = 0
    I = sidx_i[idx_i]    
    invalid_mask |= i[I]!=di
    return I,invalid_mask

# Get d-rows,cols as arrays for efficient usage latet on
di,dc = np.array([j[0]  for j in d]), np.array([j[1]  for j in d])

# Get col and index data
i,c = df.index.values.astype(di.dtype),df.columns.values.astype(dc.dtype)

# Locate row indexes from d back to df
I,badmask_I = ssidx(i,di)

# Locate column indexes from d back to df
C,badmask_C = ssidx(c,dc)

badmask = badmask_I | badmask_C

goodmask = ~badmask

df.values[I[goodmask],C[goodmask]] = newval
```

Comment: I am getting the error `index i is out of bounds for axis 0 with size i` on the line `I = sidx_i[np.searchsorted(i,di,sorter=sidx_i)]`. What is this likely to mean?

Comment: @HarryStuart Are all strings in `d` guaranteed to be from the df's index and columns?

Comment: Hmmm. No, not necessarily.

Comment: @HarryStuart So, how should that case be handled? Should that tuple from d be skipped for assignment?

Comment: Yes, they should be skipped. But it would be nice if they were flagged, even just printed to the screen so I can conduct some further investigation as to why.

Comment: `[element[0] for element in d]` and `[element[1] for element in d]` are definitely subsets of the DataFrame's rows and columns respectively. I have ensured that to be the case now. What are the required conditions for your code to work?

Comment: Got it to work, I was accidentally swapping some rows and columns but I've fixed that now. Sorry for the trouble! Thanks for the help, this method is a factor of 10 faster than the other answer.

Comment: @HarryStuart Added a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(0)[1]).rename_axis(None).max(level=0)
```

Or use `zip` with `Series`:

```
lst = list(zip(*d))
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(lst[1], index = lst[0])).max(level=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   x  y
a  1  1
b  0  1
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the list has repeated elements as the resulting DataFrame repeats such rows/columns. I've updated my example.